# ERROR: OnBackPressed(); not working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, onbackpressed

Why is exiting the application not working? When open drawer_layout closes but doesn't exit, what am I missing?

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        val mBackPressed: Long = 0
        val intervalTime = 2000

        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            if (mBackPressed + intervalTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                super.onBackPressed()
                return
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    baseContext,
                    "Tap back button in order to exit",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to say? What do you mean exiting not working and why you tagged `android-studio`

Comment: which line in the code is the one that supposed to "exit"?

Comment: I work in Android studio. Exiting the application does not work.

Comment: No code that exit application in your code, check below answer and put it the two pieces of code inside the block where you want to exit

Comment: I want to implement an exit when the back button is quickly pressed (2 times), clicked once - it shows messages "to click again", and when pressed and when the drawer_layout is closed, it shows messages but the exit does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the value `mBackPressed` with the `System.getCurrentTimeMills()` and this will loop again and again.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        val mBackPressed: Long = 0
        val intervalTime = 2000

        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.LEFT)
        } else {
            if (mBackPressed + intervalTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                super.onBackPressed()
                finishAffinity();
                return
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext,
                        "Tap back button in order to exit",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
             mbackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis()

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try seperating the if conditions to close navigation drawer and app close.